# How do I save an AzureRM context that only has access to select subscriptions?

Tags: powershell, azure

Context: I am creating a PS Module for a project that will interact with Azure KeyVault. Anyone who uses the module will need to import an Azure context to have permissions to access KeyVault (or have permissions themselves, but lets assume that's not an option. I wont know who or how many people will be using it). Ideally I should be able to share an AzureRm context file with teammates, but Id like to make sure that the file that I give cant be used to access anything other than the KeyVault.

How do I create an AzureRm context file (profile.ctx, profile.json) with the Save-AzureRmContext command or something similar that only has access to select subscriptions or resources?

Answer (score 0):

Thats not how you should handle this. You should créate a role and assign it to subscription\resource group and users. This way they will only have access to the resources you gave them access to.

Also, you shouldnt share context as it is not supported and you wont be able to distinguish who did what using logs (as all the operations will be carried out by one user).

Comment: This would be ideal but I don't know who or how many people will be using it, so I would consistently have to update the role's user list.

Comment: well, you could (by the same logic) créate a single user with minimal rights for all of those people. not that its a great idea, but

Answer (score 0):

**Currently there is not a way to accomplish this.** With Azure publish profiles you can accomplish something similar, granting deployment access to anyone within a subscription, resource group, or app [1] but that functionality isn't what i'm looking for and is not available with the AzureRmContext anyway. This functionality may never be available due to the purpose of the AzureRmContext reflecting individual ownership.

For those wondering, Instead of pursuing this route for authentication with the KeyVault for my PS Module, I created an Azure AAD app and granted the app access to the KeyVault. Then through PS I added certificate authentication to the app. This allows me to create an Auth token with the app id and cert private key which I place in the headers of requests I make to the KeyVault through their api. I now can hand off this PS module to my team and as long as they have the certificate they can use the module to access the KeyVault. Most importantly, this certificate is not tied to my personal credentials and will only allow others to access resources the app has been granted access to. I used this link [2] to do this, while it is a bit dated a little bit of research will get it working for you.

[1]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deployment-credentials
[2]https://hindenes.com/trondsworking/2015/07/19/certificate-based-authentication-to-azure-resource-manager-using-powershell/